# VSTO: Manually replace URL in Outlook MailItem with hyperlink

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook AddIn that extracts links from a MailItem before the message is sent.  The AddIn relies on the "AutoFormat As You Type" feature to replace internet paths with Hyperlinks.  Outlook seems to do a good job of automatically converting these paths to hyperlinks as long as it knows the user is finished typing the path before the "Send" button is pushed.  However, if the user had just typed a valid url and then hit send, Outlook will not replace that URL with a link because the replacement only happens after it determines the user is finished typing the link.  In other words, if the last thing the user typed was "stackoverflow.com", then Outlook will not replace this with a link.  On the other hand, if the last thing the user typed was "stackoverflow.com " (notice the trailing space), then Outlook automatically replaces the url with a link as soon as the space character is inserted because that signifies the end of the url.

I am using Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler to access the MailItem before it is sent:

```
Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

Where Application_ItemSend() looks something like this:

```
private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem MailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

        string body = MailItem.HTMLBody;

        // Process links
        // How do I make sure all URLs have been converted to links at this point?
    }
}
```

From within Application_ItemSend() I need to ensure that all URLs have been converted to links.

If I open the message from my "Sent Items" Folder after it has been sent then I can see that at some point between calling Application_ItemSend() and saving the message, Outlook has converted the last URL ("stackoverflow.com") to a link.  I need to be able to force that conversion from within Application_ItemSend(), but I have been unable to figure out what code Outlook is executing to trigger replacing the URL with a link.

I have experimented with using a regular expression to find URLs and then replace them, but this gets messy and I have not found a regular expression that does not miss a lot of valid URLs, as well as mis-match on non-valid URLs.  Besides that, who wants to re-invent the wheel if Microsoft already has code to do this.

I tried executing MailItem.Save() from within Application_ItemSend(), hoping that is what caused the URL replacement that occurs between Application_ItemSend() and the item being saved in the "Sent Items" folder, but it does not.

What code can I execute from within Application_ItemSend() to force URLs to be replaced with links?

Comment: Without any guarantees, but try to look in the WordEditor property of the Inspector itself. This will return a Document object from the Word API which contains a "Hyperlinks" collection - maybe the link is already present there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.aspx

Comment: you can use emailbody.type=Html and then append href as your requirement

Comment: mnkypete.  That is what I ended up doing.  Thank you.